# Assign network response sooner

Tags: ios, network-programming

I'm developing an app that relies on a web service backend.  I have a separate class `API` to handle all network activities and send the data to the relevant view controllers.

I have a `NSURLSession.dataTaskWithRequest()` which sends my data via POST to my API and returns a response.  I figured it would be best to have a single variable `networkResponse` in my API class with a getter and setter as I'll only ever need one response at a time.

In my ViewController, I have a login form which makes a request to the API and will log the user in depending on the response.  If the credentials are incorrect, it returns the response in a UIAlertController.

On testing incorrect credentials, I've found that the response is not getting called in time for the AlertController, so it just shows a blank message.  If I dismiss it and click login again straight away, It shows the response.  How would I go about getting it to display sooner?

login function:

```
class func login (username: String, password: String) {
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authorization]
    let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(root)PHP/login.php")!

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    var returnString : NSString = ""
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var networkTask = mySession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        var err : NSError?

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            /* Setting response variable here */
            self.setNetworkResponse(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        }
    }
    networkTask.resume()
}
```

calling API:

```
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !txtUsername.text.isEmpty || !txtPassword.text.isEmpty {
        API.login(txtUsername.text, password: txtPassword.text)
```

Alert:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "segueLogin" {
        if API.getNetworkResponse() !== "true" {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message: API.getNetworkResponse() as String, preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While its probably not the most ideal solution, I've managed to fix the problem by setting a delay, using `dispatch_after` in the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` to delay the alert by about 5 seconds.  The message appears first time now which is what I'm looking for.